# How do you link a marker from a mapview to a native map in react native using airbnb/react-native-maps?

Tags: react-native

From my react native mapview I want to let the user click on the marker to take them to their native map app so that they can get full featured things like directions, etc..

How do I link the marker to their native mapping app?

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a url with your marker's location by following Apples [Map Links guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html). Then use the React Native [Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) api to link the url from your app.

Comment: What about for Android ?  Is there a link format that is cross platform?  Or is there also a specific format for android?